# XSLT: filter and retrieve different elements

Tags: xpath

```
<cars>
 <car>
  <name v="speedy"/>
  <type v="sport"/>
  <engine>
    <hp>300</hp>
  </engine>
 <car>
 <car>
  <name v="biggo"/>
  <type v="truck"/>
  <engine>
    <hp>190</hp>
  </engine>
 <car>
</cars>
```

I have a problem in building a xpath-term that gives my biggos horsepower.

I am not sure how to filter and get the value of something that is not in the filtered element.

Comment: Those are two questions. Please, identify clearly the element you want to select.

Comment: //cars/car[./name/@v='biggo']/engine/hp?

Comment: @MarvinSmit It's not useful to start a locator step with the document element and the descendant axis. Also there is no need for self node abbreviation in the predicate. `/cars/car[name/@v='biggo']/engine/hp` would be better. But It doesn't answer _"how to filter and get the value of something that is not in the filtered element"_ part.